# hide elements appears when i forward email

Tags: html, css, image, email

i want to hide an img tag on an email template so i use this inline css:

```
display: none; max-height: 0; width: 0;
```

it works fine.
I tested the email and the img was hidden in outlook, gmail and yahoo.

The problem is that when i forward the email the image is showed back.
I inspect the forwarded email source code and the style on img tag and the css was there except the

```
display: none;
```

To sum up, i want (if any) a solution to hide an image even if the mail is forwarded.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're hiding that element.. Why not just remove it all together?

Comment: Do you forward the email with your email client or with PHP?

Comment: @Jay because i show it on mobile devices!

Comment: @D4V1D email client( both oulook and gmail )

Comment: See point n°8 in [this article](http://www.webdevdoor.com/html-css/html-email-development-tips/): "*When a HTML email is forwarded, the results from the new recipient cannot be guranteed as many email clients will strip out most of your nice clean code and try and replace it with their own. Thunderbird seems pretty good at keeping the layout, Outlook (as you might expect) is terrible at retaining formatting.*". It seems like a common problem then.